# Getting full names from NER

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

From reading through the docs and playing with the API, it looks like CoreNLP will tell me the NER tags per token, but it won't help me extract out full names from a sentence. For example:

```
Input: John Wayne and Mary have coffee
CoreNLP Output: (John,PERSON) (Wayne,PERSON) (and,O) (Mary,PERSON) (have,O) (coffee,O)
Desired Result: list of PERSON ==> [John Wayne, Mary]
```

Unless there is some flag I missed, I believe to do this I will need to parse the tokens and glue together successive tokens tagged PERSON.

Can someone confirm that this is indeed what I need to do? I mostly want to know if there is some flag or utility in CoreNLP that does something like this for me. Bonus points if someone has a utility (ideally Java, since I'm using the Java API) that does this and wants to share :)

Thanks!

PS: There was a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842982/tagging-full-name-in-stanford-ner), which seems to suggest the answer is "roll your own", but it was never confirmed by anyone else.

Comment: I don't know a lot about CoreNLP, but usually in NLP pipeline there's the notion of Noun Chunks or Noun phrases. These are the language most basic building blocks, like NOUN VERB NOUN. Usually in more complex strucutures, the noun phrases are "hierarchical", meaning that the noun can be composite. This is also addressed by Dependency Parsing. Maybe you could check for the entities then match them into these noun chunks, looking for names as nouns. Also, consider looking at Semantic Role Labeling (get the agents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are probably looking for [entity mentions](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html#entity-mention-detection) instead of or as well as NER tags. For example with the [Simple API](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html):

```
new Sentence("Jimi Hendrix was the greatest").nerTags()
[PERSON, PERSON, O, O, O]

new Sentence("Jimi Hendrix was the greatest").mentions()
[Jimi Hendrix]
```

The link above has an example with the traditional non-simple API using a good old `StanfordCoreNLP` pipeline

Answer (score 2):

This is shown in the basic Java API example on this link:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Here is the full Java API example, there is a section on entity mentions:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import java.util.*;


public class BasicPipelineExample {

  public static String text = "Joe Smith was born in California. " +
      "In 2017, he went to Paris, France in the summer. " +
      "His flight left at 3:00pm on July 10th, 2017. " +
      "After eating some escargot for the first time, Joe said, \"That was delicious!\" " +
      "He sent a postcard to his sister Jane Smith. " +
      "After hearing about Joe's trip, Jane decided she might go to France one day.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // set the list of annotators to run
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
    // set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being set to use the neural algorithm
    props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // create a document object
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
    // annnotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    // examples

    // 10th token of the document
    CoreLabel token = document.tokens().get(10);
    System.out.println("Example: token");
    System.out.println(token);
    System.out.println();

    // text of the first sentence
    String sentenceText = document.sentences().get(0).text();
    System.out.println("Example: sentence");
    System.out.println(sentenceText);
    System.out.println();

    // second sentence
    CoreSentence sentence = document.sentences().get(1);

    // list of the part-of-speech tags for the second sentence
    List<String> posTags = sentence.posTags();
    System.out.println("Example: pos tags");
    System.out.println(posTags);
    System.out.println();

    // list of the ner tags for the second sentence
    List<String> nerTags = sentence.nerTags();
    System.out.println("Example: ner tags");
    System.out.println(nerTags);
    System.out.println();

    // constituency parse for the second sentence
    Tree constituencyParse = sentence.constituencyParse();
    System.out.println("Example: constituency parse");
    System.out.println(constituencyParse);
    System.out.println();

    // dependency parse for the second sentence
    SemanticGraph dependencyParse = sentence.dependencyParse();
    System.out.println("Example: dependency parse");
    System.out.println(dependencyParse);
    System.out.println();

    // kbp relations found in fifth sentence
    List<RelationTriple> relations =
        document.sentences().get(4).relations();
    System.out.println("Example: relation");
    System.out.println(relations.get(0));
    System.out.println();

    // entity mentions in the second sentence
    List<CoreEntityMention> entityMentions = sentence.entityMentions();
    System.out.println("Example: entity mentions");
    System.out.println(entityMentions);
    System.out.println();

    // coreference between entity mentions
    CoreEntityMention originalEntityMention = document.sentences().get(3).entityMentions().get(1);
    System.out.println("Example: original entity mention");
    System.out.println(originalEntityMention);
    System.out.println("Example: canonical entity mention");
    System.out.println(originalEntityMention.canonicalEntityMention().get());
    System.out.println();

    // get document wide coref info
    Map<Integer, CorefChain> corefChains = document.corefChains();
    System.out.println("Example: coref chains for document");
    System.out.println(corefChains);
    System.out.println();

    // get quotes in document
    List<CoreQuote> quotes = document.quotes();
    CoreQuote quote = quotes.get(0);
    System.out.println("Example: quote");
    System.out.println(quote);
    System.out.println();

    // original speaker of quote
    // note that quote.speaker() returns an Optional
    System.out.println("Example: original speaker of quote");
    System.out.println(quote.speaker().get());
    System.out.println();

    // canonical speaker of quote
    System.out.println("Example: canonical speaker of quote");
    System.out.println(quote.canonicalSpeaker().get());
    System.out.println();

  }

}
```